# Convert pandas df to list of lists with varying length

Tags: python, pandas, list, time-complexity

I have a dataframe just like this and I need to convert it to a list of lists according to the "desired output"

```
    d = {'0': ['A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C','C'],
         '1': [4.3,3.2,2.1,9.1,2.0,2.8,1.7,0.8,0.2]}
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    
            0   1
        0   A   4.3
        1   A   3.0
        2   A   2.1
        3   B   9.0
        4   B   2.0
        5   C   2.8
        6   C   1.7
        7   C   0.8
        8   C   0.2
    
    # Desired output
[[4.3, 3.2, 2.1], [9.1, 2.0], [2.8, 1.7, 0.8, 0.2]]
```

I wrote the following to do it and it gets the job done:

```
d_tuples = [*list(zip(df[0],df[1]))]
keys = df[0].unique()
list_of_lists = []
for key in keys:
    list_of_lists+=[[tup[1] for tup in d_tuples if tup[0] == key]]
list_of_lists  #[[4.3, 3.2, 2.1], [9.1, 2.0], [2.8, 1.7, 0.8, 0.2]]
```

However, the original database is about 25,000,000 rows long and its taking some time, I was wondering if theres a more efficient way to write it.

EDIT: "desired output" means a list_of_lists where each list contains the values in column "1" for one of the unique values in column "0"

EDIT2: Added timeit results
[image]

Comment: 25 million? i really would recommend a sql db for this.

Comment: _I need to convert it to a list of lists according to the "desired output"_ Can you explain the actual algorithm, to make things simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

groupby object is dict, you may use it to avoid `agg` to speed up more

```
In [229]: [v.tolist() for v in df.set_index('1').groupby('0').groups.values()]
Out[229]: [[4.3, 3.2, 2.1], [9.1, 2.0], [2.8, 1.7, 0.8, 0.2]]
```

---

**Timing on 90K rows**

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000)

%timeit [v.tolist() for v in df.set_index('1').groupby('0').groups.values()]
15.2 ms ± 425 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.groupby('0')['1'].agg(list).tolist()
32.8 ms ± 623 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [236]: %%timeit
     ...: d_tuples = [*list(zip(df['0'],df['1']))]
     ...: keys = df['0'].unique()
     ...: list_of_lists = []
     ...: for key in keys:
     ...:     list_of_lists+=[[tup[1] for tup in d_tuples if tup[0] == key]]
     ...:
69.4 ms ± 754 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

use `.groupby` with `.agg(list)` with another `.tolist()` call

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.groupby('0')['1'].agg(list).tolist()
#out.
[[4.3, 3.2, 2.1], [9.1, 2.0], [2.8, 1.7, 0.8, 0.2]]
```

Comment: Thanks its probably more elegant and compact than my code but not as fast

Comment: @lfc i would disagree, your using vectorised methods over for loops I would be extremely suprised if your code ran faster than the above method.

Comment: I just attached the timeit results though..You think maybe if the dataset had more keys (like the original data would have) your code would be faster?

Comment: test it with a larger dataframe, do `df = pd.concat([df] * 10000)` you'll find the above method to run twice as fast @lfc also using `df.groupby('0')['1'].agg(tuple).values` gets me much faster results.

Answer (score 1):

May be using `apply()`

```
list(df.groupby('0')['1'].apply(list))

#[[4.3, 3.2, 2.1], [9.1, 2.0], [2.8, 1.7, 0.8, 0.2]]
```

Comment: Thanks its probably more elegant and compact than my code but its not quite faster

Answer (score 1):

There probably isn't a faster way to do it with default python lists, unfortunately. Depending on data you have you might use numpy arrays (they are memory efficient, so that will give you a speed-up) — i.e., `list(df.groupby('0')['1'].apply(np.array))`. Depending on the number of unique keys, speed-up can be anywhere from 10% to 100% (according to local tests on my machine).

P.S. By the way, don't test with small dataframes. Create a bigger one like this:

```
N = 500
keys = np.arange(0, N)

df = {
    '0': keys[np.random.randint(0, N, size=int(1e6))],
    '1': np.random.rand(int(1e6))
}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```